# Heroku not recognizing NumPy in requirements.txt

Tags: python, numpy, heroku, flask, requirements.txt

I've been having difficulty trying to run **[python-recsys](http://ocelma.net/software/python-recsys/build/html/installation.html)** with Flask on Heroku

One of the requirements for python-recsys is that it requires numpy

My requirements.txt is

```
decorator==4.0.4
numpy==1.6.2
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
networkx==1.10
git+https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys.git
scipy==0.16.1
Werkzeug==0.10.4
wheel==0.24.0
Divisi2==2.2.5
```

Outputs

```
Counting objects: 4434, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4353/4353), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4434/4434), 33.17 MiB | 470 KiB/s, done.
Total 4434 (delta 394), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.10)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote:        Collecting git+https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys.git          (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Cloning https://github.com/ocelma/python-recsys.git to    /tmp/pip-nCYxck-build
remote:        Collecting decorator==4.0.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading decorator-4.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz (2.6MB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==0.24 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==2.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==0.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting networkx==1.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading networkx-1.10.tar.gz (1.2MB)
remote:        Collecting scipy==0.16.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading scipy-0.16.1.tar.gz (12.2MB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==0.10.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-0.10.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (293kB)
remote:        Collecting wheel==0.24.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading wheel-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63kB)
remote:        Collecting Divisi2==2.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading Divisi2-2.2.5.tar.gz (10.9MB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            This package requires NumPy.
remote:            
remote:            On a Debian / Ubuntu system, you can run:
remote:              sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-dev
remote:            
remote:            Otherwise it will probably suffice to:
remote:              sudo easy_install numpy
remote:            
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-    build-U6idSN/Divisi2
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

It appears from the output that numpy was installed (Line 2 )
but it outputs as uninstalled

I've tried different variations including different versions of numpy
I've tried putting the numpy requirement in different positions in the requirements.txt

Any ideas as to what is causing this error?
Is there a better way to install numpy?

Comment: You probably need the python headers installed so it can build numpy. Have you tried `apt-get install python-dev`?

Comment: Did you `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-dev` as suggested?

Comment: I was not sure where to implement the 'sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-dev' -if I am running on a Mac would I be able to use 'sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-dev' or would it not matter due to it running on Heroku

Comment: Would 'sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-dev' go in requirements.txt?

Comment: You need to run 'heroku shell bash' first to ssh into your heroku box. Then you can try apt-get

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to fix it as advised by @MatO:

Run locally `python.exe -m pip install python-dev-tools`

Regenerate requirements.txt with  `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Add changes with `git add .`

Commit `git commit -m "v5"`

Push to Heroku `git push heroku master`

After deployment I was able to run my app, although I got warning:

> Warning: Your slug size (397 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB)
>   which may affect boot time.

My app use to be 59 MB and now is bigger than if it would be if I deployed it without virtualenv.